# Grails select integer value and string value

Tags: grails, select, integer

I have two domain classes...

First:

```
class Employee {
    String vorname
    String nachname
    Department department
}
```

Second:

```
class Department {
    Integer number
    String description
}
```

...and I want to create a dropdown in Grails.

My code looks like this:

```
    <g:select id="department" name="department.description" from="${workloadreport.Department.list()}" optionValue="bezeichnung" optionKey="id" required=""
          value="${employeeInstance.department?.id}" class="many-to-one" noSelection="${['null':'Please select...']}"/>
```

But I want to show the number + description as one value in dropdown.

Like:

- Value 1 : 30 General Services
- Value 2 : 40 Product Services
- Value 3 : 50 Other Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the resulting html to look something like this for an option element ...

```
<option value="1">1 : 30 General Services</option>
```

this should produce it (there may be typo, I haven't tested it):

```
<g:select id="department" name="department.description"
   from="${workloadreport.Department.list()}" optionKey="id" required=""
   value="${employeeInstance.department?.id}" class="many-to-one"
   noSelection="${['null':'Please select...']}"
   optionValue="${{it.id + ' : ' + it.number + ' ' + it.description}}" 
/>
```

** note you probably have a typo in your **from** property. If you just want to generate a list of options from all departments, your from should look like this

```
<g:select ... from="${Department.list()}" .../>
```

Comment: yes you're right, but your code example didn't fixed my problem. I get an error : > Message;
    No such property: description for class: workloadreport.Department

Comment: i updated the answer, it might be a typo with your from in the select

Comment: doesn't help. Now i get this error : > Message: Cannot invoke method list() on null object. Did you have any other solutions? Thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: your are probably not importing the Department class in your view. Look at top of view and you probably only see something like import="...Employee". You'll need to explicitly add another import for Department or wildcard to include all

Comment: Okay now the import line is  : <%@ page import="workloadreport.Department; workloadreport.Employee" %> and the optionValue line is : optionValue="${{it.number + ' ' + it.description}}" but i get this error again : Message: No such property: description for class: workloadreport.Department

Comment: Does the error give you "Possible solutions:..". Do you have a typo? Maybe try exit, clean, and run-app. What happens if you only have it.number without it.description - does that work?

Comment: Hey.. i have try clean. That was the solution. Thanks a lot.